# List files whose names consist of two digits

Tags: regex, bash, find

I'm trying to find all file or directory that only contain two digits in the current directory.

The regex for exactly two digits is

```
/^\d{2}$/
```

So I tried the following but because of the backslash and forwardslash I got stuck

```
find path ".//^\d{9}$/"
```

I use "./[regex]" because I am looking file or directory that is in the current directory

Comment: Is the file name literally just two digits and nothing else, even an extension?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `find` here. The command below will list files and directories whose name consists of two digits in the current directory.

```
printf '%s\n' ./[0-9][0-9]
# drop `./' if you don't need it
```

If you have to use a regex for some reason, here is how it's done with GNU `find` and BSD `find` respectively:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '\./[0-9]{2}'
```

```
find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[0-9]{2}'
```

And with any POSIX-compliant `find`, this will do the same thing:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '*[!0-9]*' -name '??'
# number of question marks determines the length of filename
```

Some may argue that `[0-9]` may match more than digits from 0 through 9; if that's a concern, set `LC_ALL` to `C` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` like so:

```
find . -name '*[0-9]*[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*[[:digit:]]{2}.*$"
```

Specify regular expression type with the regextype flag as well as regular expression to search for with -regex. Search for all entries that have 2 digits any where in the directory/filename.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it